# Поставить [] .attr('name','xf_address'+total)

Tags: jquery

Как поставить между

```
.attr('name','[xf_address'+total])
```

Вот так?

```
    /* Добавление полей с адресами */
var total = 0;
function add_new_image(){
   if (total == 10)
   throw alert("Можно добавить только 10 адресов");

   total++;
   $('<div>')
   .attr('id','xfield_holder_address_'+total)
   .addClass('form-group')
   .append('<label class="control-label col-sm-2">Адрес #'+total+' </label>')
   .append (
       $('<div>')
       .addClass('col-sm-10')
       .append(
           $('<input type="text" /></div>')
           .addClass('form-control width-500')
           .attr('id','xf_address'+total)
           .attr('name','xf_address'+total)
       )                               

    )
     .insertAfter('[id^=xfield_holder_address]:last');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    add_new_image();
});
$('#xf_address').after('<input type="button" value="Добавить еще адрес" id="add" onclick="return add_new_image();">');
```

Comment: Мы ничего не поняли. Поставить что между чем? `.attr('name','[xf_address'+total+']')`?

Comment: есть строчка
.attr('name','xf_address'+total)
мне нужно поставить так
.attr('name','[xf_address'+total])
но не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.attr('name','[xf_address'+total+']')
```